# Android linking lmediandk: multiple definition of PROPERTY_VENDOR

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, linker

I have a class `MyClass` which is part of the static library `MyLibrary`. `MyClass` includes `<media/NdkMediaDrm.h>`.

`MyLibrary` has an Android.mk file which builds a static library. Within this I have linked the media library:

`LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lmediandk`

However I get the following error message when compiling:

```
ld: error: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libMyLibrary.a(MyClass.o): multiple definition of 'PROPERTY_VENDOR'
ld: ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libMyLibrary.a(MyLibrary.o): previous definition here
```

I get the same error for `PROPERTY_VERSION`, `PROPERTY_DESCRIPTION`, `PROPERTY_ALGORITHMS` and `PROPERTY_DEVICE_UNIQUE_ID`.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the NDK headers, more specifically, in the `media/NdkMediaDrm.h` header. Every time you include it, it defines a new copy of these global variables.

The workaround would be to not include this particular header unless you really need it. If you actually need to include it in more than one file, you can edit it and change

```
const char *PROPERTY_VENDOR = "vendor";
```

into

```
#define PROPERTY_VENDOR "vendor"
```

(and similarly for all the other string constants).

Comment: FWIW, I sent a fix for this at https://android-review.googlesource.com/116646, let's see if it gets merged or if they fix it differently.

Comment: This fix has been merged now, so it will hopefully be included in the next version of the NDK.